# Javascript not functioning to toggle the overlay

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an overlay and a modal window on that overlay, but the javascript isn't toggling the display properties of overlay and the modal in either ways (not showing the overlay when hidden nor hiding it when displayed on the screen).

following is the code for my overlay and my modal (which is a form):

```
<div class="overlay">    
    <form id="cpass" method="post" action="{{ path('admin_cpass') }}">
        <span class="fa fa-times close" onclick="cpass()"></span><br />
        <span>Change Password</span>
        <input type="password" placeholder="old password" name="opass" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="choose new password" name="npass" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" name="cnpass" />
        <input type="submit" value="change password" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
function cpass() {
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = (document.getElementById('overlay').style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    document.getElementById('cpass').style.display = (document.getElementById('cpass').style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

note: I have used Jquery code above in the same script tag (if that may cause any problem but I think it should not).

by default, both of them, overlay and form has display property set to none when the page is loaded

even if you can do it by jquery, please let me know

Please help

Comment: Your " I have used Jquery code above" is not true. You used pure JavaScript. Maybe you should make a https://jsfiddle.net/ or add the css too at least. Also, you're trying to achieve somekind of a popup?

Comment: `cpass` is inside `overlay`... What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: `overlay` is a class, not an id

Comment: thanks rory, that was a completely stupid of me!